# Unzipping, renaming and migrating contents of GDB directory - Python

Tags: python

Currently trying to develop a catch all script that when pointed to a folder it will look through all of the subfolders and anything that is a .gdb will be moved to a new folder. Some GDBS are zipped and have a folder which then contains the GDB inside. If the GDB files have the same name once extracted, they will be appended with the suffix _2, _3, _4 and then moved to the folder with the other GDBs and won't conflict with any filenames.

Everything works except the renaming. Whereby it will rename one ok and then start placing folders inside of another gdb, before eventually failing with. WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

```
import shutil, errno, re, os, zipfile, os.path, sys


def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
    for member in zf.infolist():
        words = member.filename.split('/')
        path = dest_dir
        for word in words[:-1]:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        zf.extract(member, path)


results = []
input_path = sys.argv[1]
output_path = sys.argv[2]


if input_path not in output_path:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
            for f in files:                        
                    if f.endswith(".zip") or f.endswith(".ZIP"):
                            unzip(os.path.join(path,f), path)

if input_path not in output_path:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
            counter = 2
            for dir_name in subdirs:
                    if os.path.join(path, dir_name).endswith(".gdb") or os.path.join(path, dir_name).endswith(".GDB"):

                            if os.path.exists(output_path + "\\" + dir_name):
                                    print "Moving " + os.path.join(path, dir_name) + " To " + output_path + "\\" + str(counter) + dir_name
                                    os.rename(os.path.join(path, dir_name), output_path + "\\" + dir_name[:-4] + "_" + str(counter) + ".gdb")
                                    counter + 1
                            else:
                                    print "Moving " + os.path.join(path, dir_name) + " To " + output_path
                                    shutil.move(os.path.join(path, dir_name), output_path)
else:

    print "########################################"
    print "########################################"
    print "Please select a different output path"
    print "The output path should not be contained"
    print "         In the input path"
    print "########################################"
    print "########################################"
```

Any help anyone could give would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!